# Make pytorch model return data as float16

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, ram

I try to finetune a pretrained LLM with transformers/pytorch. However,I can't evaluate it, because the number of samples in validation set * the number of classes * number of bytes per float64 is too big to fit in my RAM.

Is there a way to force the model to return a tensor of dtype float32 or even float16 ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should batch the validation set into small enough batches that each one of them can fit in ram. The dimension of the batches does not influence the result of the validation step as no gradients are modified.
If you still can't fit the batches in memory you could try to [enable mixed precision](https://pytorch.org/blog/accelerating-training-on-nvidia-gpus-with-pytorch-automatic-mixed-precision/).

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know if this kind of batching is doable with transformers ? Actually if I understood well, the predict is ok (in the GPU) but when putting it in CPU (for calculate accuracy), it OOM. So I dont think mixed precision would be useful at this point; anyway I already use it

Comment: Can't you just compute the accuracy on GPU directly?

Comment: Maybe yes, but I dont think built in transformers lib allows that.